# Rails ajax form, does its job but still tries to redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a remote form for @vote, which submits a choice id. I simply want to render a partial instead of redirect it after the successful create action.
The action is successful, the vote is created, my create.js.erb is not reached and it gives a RoutingError. Server window looks to me like its processing html format. Any help appreciated!

Form:

```
 = form_for Vote.new, url: poll_votes_path(@model), remote: true do |f|
    %ul
      - choices.each do |choice|
        %li
          %label
            = radio_button_tag 'choice', choice.id, false, required: true
            = choice.body
    .submit
      = f.submit "Stemmen", class: "send-vote", id: "poll_#{@model.id}"
```

Controller:

```
def create

  @poll = Poll.find(params[:poll_id])
  vote = Vote.new(poll: @poll, choice_id: params[:choice], ip: request.remote_ip, email: params[:email])

  if vote.save
    # cookies["#{@poll.id.to_s.crypt('lenniskink')}"] = {value: params[:choice], expires: 1.year.from_now}
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

routes:

```
resources :polls, path: 'peilingen' do
  member do
    get :results
    put :sort
  end
  resources :votes, path: 'stemmen', only: [:create, :index]
end
```

create.js

Browser:

```
ActionController::RoutingError at /peilingen/581/stemmen
Not Found
```

Server:

```
Started POST "/peilingen/581/stemmen" for ::1 at 2017-02-18 14:08:53 +0100
Processing by Admin::VotesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "choice"=>"2711", "commit"=>"Stemmen", "poll_id"=>"581"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 461  ORDER BY login ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (2.0ms)  UPDATE `users` SET `last_request_at` = '2017-02-18 13:08:53', `perishable_token` = 'ouUIlXRADq3WTnrysQGC', `updated_at` = '2017-02-18 13:08:53' WHERE `users`.`id` = 461
   (1.0ms)  COMMIT
  Organization Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `organizations`.* FROM `organizations` INNER JOIN `organizations_users` ON `organizations`.`id` = `organizations_users`.`organization_id` WHERE `organizations_users`.`user_id
` = 461
  User Store (29.8ms)  {"id":461}
  Poll Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `polls`.* FROM `polls` WHERE `polls`.`id` = 581 LIMIT 1
   (1.0ms)  BEGIN
  Choice Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `choices`.* FROM `choices` WHERE `choices`.`id` = 2711 LIMIT 1
  SQL (24.5ms)  INSERT INTO `votes` (`poll_id`, `choice_id`, `ip`, `created_at`) VALUES (581, 2711, '::1', '2017-02-18 13:08:53')
  SQL (0.8ms)  UPDATE `choices` SET `votes_count` = COALESCE(`votes_count`, 0) + 1 WHERE `choices`.`id` = 2711
   (0.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `votes` WHERE `votes`.`poll_id` = 581
  SQL (2.7ms)  UPDATE `polls` SET `votes_count` = 157, `updated_at` = '2017-02-18 13:08:53' WHERE `polls`.`id` = 581
   (1.6ms)  COMMIT
Completed 404 Not Found in 139ms (Searchkick: 29.8ms | ActiveRecord: 37.1ms)

ActionController::RoutingError - Not Found:
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:26:in `not_found'
```

Routes:

```
results_poll GET    /peilingen/:id/results(.:format)                          admin/polls#results
                        sort_poll PUT    /peilingen/:id/sort(.:format)                             admin/polls#sort
                       poll_votes GET    /peilingen/:poll_id/stemmen(.:format)                     admin/votes#index
                                  POST   /peilingen/:poll_id/stemmen(.:format)                     admin/votes#create
                            polls GET    /peilingen(.:format)                                      admin/polls#index
                                  POST   /peilingen(.:format)                                      admin/polls#create
                         new_poll GET    /peilingen/new(.:format)                                  admin/polls#new
                        edit_poll GET    /peilingen/:id/edit(.:format)                             admin/polls#edit
                             poll GET    /peilingen/:id(.:format)                                  admin/polls#show
                                  PATCH  /peilingen/:id(.:format)                                  admin/polls#update
                                  PUT    /peilingen/:id(.:format)                                  admin/polls#update
                                  DELETE /peilingen/:id(.:format)                                  admin/polls#destroy
```

Comment: Post your `rake routes`

Comment: My first gut feel is the resources declaration where you say `polls`

Comment: The request is not being sent as an ajax request - in that case the log would say that the request format is `js` as that is the default for rails_ujs. Have you tried checking the browser console for errors as this is most likely due to broken javascript that is interfering with rails_ujs?